# ALSA: notification when underrun occurs?

Tags: callback, notifications, alsa

Is there a possibility to be notified by ALSA (through a callback or similar) when an underrun occurs during playback?

I would be using the snd_async_handler_t but unfortunately [snd_async_add_pcm_handler()](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#g0d343597cdce35871a5010b6e6d5535b) fails, telling me that this function is not implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALSA will not notice than an underrun has occured until it reads the current position, which happens

- when your application calls an ALSA function that needs the position, or
- in the interrupt handler, which will wake up any currently waiting snd_pcm_write*() call.

So, in practice, a separate notification would not make sense.

Usually, you just check the return value of snd_pcm_write*(), or call snd_pcm_status() explicitly.